# How can i run all migrations for all plugins in cakephp 3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I know I can run bin/cake Migrations migrate --plugin MyPlugin

but I use 50+ plugins in my project and id liked to run all migrations in all plugins with one command is this possible?

Comment: Just manually iterate over the plugins that need migrations to run in your deploy.sh script etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no straight forward command for running migrations for all plugins. However, you could put together a simple Shell script to do this.

You can retrieve a list of all the loaded plugins for an app using:-

```
$plugins = Plugin::loaded();
```

You can then run the migrations for each plugin using [`dispatchShell`](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html#Cake%5CConsole%5CShell::dispatchShell) which allows you to run a command from another Shell:-

```
$this->dispatchShell(
    'migrations',
    'migrate',
    '-p',
    $plugin
);
```

Each argument for the migration is passed as an argument to `dispatchShell`.

So, putting all that together into a Shell script:-

```
<?php
// src/Shell/InstallShell.php
namespace App\Shell;

use Cake\Console\Shell;
use Cake\Core\Plugin;

class InstallShell extends Shell
{
    public function plugins()
    {
        $plugins = Plugin::loaded();
        foreach ($plugins as $plugin) {
            $this->dispatchShell(
                'migrations',
                'migrate',
                '-p',
                $plugin
            );
        }
    }
}
```

This script would be called like `$ bin/cake install plugins`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible there several ways to achieve this
write shell script and save in bin directory with all 50 plugins migrations
or you can also use cakephp shell Api [read here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html)

Comment: so i can only do this by creating a shell task not with the command bin/cake Migrations ?

Comment: see here https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html#migrate-applying-migrations

Comment: # Run all the migrations
$ bin/cake migrations migrate

Comment: $ bin/cake migrations migrate does not migrate plugins

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers didn’t quite work for my Cake ~4.1.0 application because of various deprecations that have occurred since, so I made some adjustments. Perhaps it is of use to others. This is in `scr/Command/MigrationsCommand.php`:

```php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Command;

use Cake\Command\Command;
use Cake\Console\Arguments;
use Cake\Console\ConsoleIo;
use Cake\Console\ConsoleOptionParser;
use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Migrations\Command\MigrationsMigrateCommand;

class MigrationsCommand extends Command
{
    protected function buildOptionParser(ConsoleOptionParser $parser): ConsoleOptionParser
    {
        $parser->addArgument('plugins', ['help' => 'Run all plugin migrations']);

        return $parser;
    }

    public function execute(Arguments $args, ConsoleIo $io): ?int
    {
        if($args->getArgument('plugins'))
        {
            $plugins = Plugin::loaded();
            $migrations = new MigrationsMigrateCommand();

            foreach ($plugins as $plugin) {
                $io->out('Run migrations for ' . $plugin . ':');

                $this->executeCommand(
                    $migrations,
                    [
                        '-p',
                        $plugin
                    ]
                );
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I run it using:

```shell
cake migrations plugins
```

Please note that it tries **all** your plugins. This causes it to throw an error for the plugins that don’t have migrations defined. You could work around this, but I was fine with this behavior.

Answer (score -1):

I have improved "drmonkeyninja" answer with the following code. This way the migrations only run when they have not been migrated before and they migrate in order of the timestamp given in the file name.

```
<?php
// src/Shell/InstallShell.php
namespace App\Shell;

use Cake\Console\Shell;
use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Migrations\Migrations;

class InstallShell extends Shell
{
    public function plugins()
    {
        $migrationsClass = new Migrations();
        $migrations = [];
        $pluginMigrations = [];
        $plugins = Plugin::loaded();
        foreach ($plugins as $plugin) {
            $statuses = $migrationsClass->status(['plugin' => $plugin]);
            $path = Plugin::path($plugin) . 'config' . DS . 'Migrations' . DS;
            if (@$handle = opendir($path)) {
                while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
                    if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
                        $timestamp = substr($entry, 0, 14);
                        if(!is_numeric($timestamp)) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        foreach($statuses as $status){
                            if ($status['status'] == 'up' && $status['id'] === $timestamp) {
                                continue(2);
                            }
                        }

                        $migrations[] = $timestamp;
                        $pluginMigrations[$timestamp] = $plugin;
                    }
                }
                closedir($handle);
            }
        }

        sort($migrations);

        foreach ($migrations as $timestamp) {
            $this->dispatchShell(
                'migrations',
                'migrate',
                '-p',
                $pluginMigrations[$timestamp],
                '-t',
                $timestamp
            ); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `bin/cake migrations migrate` already handle whether or not a migration has 
already been run?